# Fetch request returns a "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header error, but I have cors set appropriately?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, cors

I know this has been asked **countless** times on SO but none of the solutions I have found have worked for me.

I have a Node API connected to a MongoDB database with Express.

I am trying to return data to a React front-end but whenever I make a request to the API endopint I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://redacted.com' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried several solutions found from previous questions around this being asked on SO but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

**I have tried the following solutions:**

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000', methods: 'GET, POST', preflightContinue: false'}));
```

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
```

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http::/localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST');
    next();
```

```
app.options('*', cors());
```

Nothing seems to work and continues to throw this cross-origin error.

**Here is my full index.js for my API:**

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

let apiRoutes = require('./api-routes/routes');

let app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}))

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API is working!'));

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Running server on port 3001");
});
```

**Fetch request in React:**

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/pcg/bgproutestate');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
```

Is anyone able to please tell me **what could be the issue** and **how to solve this**? I've never had this issue with previous APIs... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Okay as soon as I posted the question I found a solution...

If I move the following code..:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http::/localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST');
    next();
```

..above this code..:

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
```

..It takes the cors policy and allows data to be fetched. I think the cors needs to be defined before you define the routes of your API. Hope this helps someone else!